# jqPlot dateAxisRendered weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

Hi I'm using jqPlot to plot a graph over time. I'm also using the dateAxisRenderer plugin to have a user friendly display over the X axis.

I'm trying to have one tick every two hours: for that, i'm trying to things:

- I'm setting `numberTicks` to `13`: in that case the first tick is at 00:00, the last is at 00:00 the next day, but the middle tick is at 12:30 and the others are evenly distributed between 0 and 12:30 (00:00, 01:55, 04:50, 06:45, 08:40, 10:35, 12:30, 14:25, 16:20, 18:15, 20:10, 22:05, 00:00);
- I'm setting `tickInterval` to `'2 hours'`: in that case I end with 13 ticks, centered on 1pm and from 00:00 to 01:00 (00:00, 03:00, 05:00, 07:00, 09:00, 11:00, 13:00, 15:00, 17:00, 19:00, 21:00, 23:00, 01:00).

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date I was working on was the 03-25-2007, the day the DST changed... the behavior was perfectly normal.

To solve the problem, I had to use UTC times.